# Swagger displays two endpoints for same method after routing-tweak

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

We have a (asp .net) web api and we are using [swagger](https://swagger.io) for online documentation.

Since we want to have more than one HttpGet-method on each controller and have the "Get"-method as default ("/") we have rewritten the routing to

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}");
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
```

This works well, but if I have a controller that looks like this

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
 {
        public Order Get(string orderId)
        {
         ...
        }
 }
```

Swagger shows it like this (like there were two methods)
[image]

We are running this config code:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace OurProject.Api
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("V3", "OurProject.Api"))
                .EnableSwaggerUi();

        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to tweak either the routing or swagger to show it as one single method (preferably the "/Orders" in the image above)

Comment: What are you using to generate your swagger spec? Swagger-Net, Swashbuckle, NSwag or some other?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Let me get back to you on that. I didnt set it up and Im out traveling right now.

Comment: Hi again (anyone :)). We are using Swashbuckle

Comment: Look in the Swashbuckle documentation for IDocumentFilters